# Create custom child node with RABL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rabl

I'd like to create JSON like this:

```
{
  "field1": "value-1",
  "field2": "value-2",
  "actions": {
    "edit": "/edit/action/url"
  }
}
```

using rabl. It doesn't work with `child` method nor i can't do it with `node` - got unknown method error. So, is it possible to create custom child node using rabl template? Say something like this:

```
collection @datas => :datas
attributes :field1, :field2
child :actions do
  node :edit do
    edit_datas_path :id
  end
end
```

***edit***
I choose this one:

```
node :actions do
  actions = {}
  actions[:edit] = edit_customer_group_path(:id)
  node :foo do
    foos = {}
    foos[:bar] = "hello"
    foos
  end
  actions
end
```

But accepted answer below is correct too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just stumbled across this issue the other day. This [ticket](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/issues/146) in RABL issues helped me. In your case, I was able to generate proper JSON using:

```
collection @datas
extends "datas/base"
node :actions do
  {:edit => root_path}
end
```

generated JSON:

```
{
  id: 1,
  actions: {
            edit: "/"
           }
}
```

Using RABL 0.5.3